# Pass the list of checked values to controller by Bean object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-ui

Trying to pass the list of selected subjects to Controller, but the bean is not receiving the list of subjects.

Here's the code that I'm trying:

```
$("#submitCreateStudent").click(function() {
      var selSubjectIds = new Array();
      $('#subjectsTableInCreateStudent').find('.jtable-data-row').each(function() {
        if (selSubjectIds.length < 1) {
          selSubjectIds.push($(this).attr('data-record-key') + '$');
        } else {
          selSubjectIds += $(this).attr('data-record-key') + '$';
        }
      });

      if (validateCreateStudentForm()) {

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('firstName', $("#firstNameInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('lastName', $("#lastNameInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('address', $("#studentAddressInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('collegeName', $("#studentCollegeNameInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('phoneNumber', $("#phoneNumberInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('email', $("#emailInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('studentDepartment', $("#departmentInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('studentBranch', $("#branchInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('DateOfBirth', $("#dobInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('DateOfReport', $("#dorInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('loginUserName', $("#studentUserNameInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('loginPassword', $("#passwordInCreateStudent").val());
        data.append('studentSubjects', selSubjectIds);

        //                        data.append('skipInitialTraining', skipInitialTraining);

        $("#maskingId").mask("Saving...");

        $.ajax({
          url: "AddStudent.do",
          data: data,
          //                           
          //Remaining code goes here.
        });
      });
```

All the details are coming to controller class except for the list of subjects which are selected check boxes.

Comment: To shorten how about using `$("form").on("submit")` and `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: understood. but will that solve problem?

Comment: Simplification is always good. Any errors in console or app log?

Comment: No error messages in console

Comment: it just need to store the elements in the jtable in to array and append it to the data field.

Comment: Please update the question with relevant Html. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53314394/edit) and click `[<>]` the snippet editor and add console.log to the line before `$("#maskingId").mask("Saving...");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks to Everyone for your efforts.I found my self a way to solve
>   this as Follows

```
var arr = "";
$('#subjectsTableInCreateStudent').find('.jtable-data-row').each(function() {
                        var record = $(this).data('record');
                        arr += record.subjectId + seperatorForGridCells;   

                    });
```

> Here the arr variable stores every ID as a String by concating with
>   Some seperator "seperatorForGridCells". Then i used StringTokenizer to
>   seperate each id and parsed each id from string type to int.

Answer (score 1):

By default, jQuery supports json format submissions

`data :{‘selSubjectIds’:selSubjectIds}` or `$(this).serialize();`

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you be more specific like where should i put this and which lines has to be replaced?

Comment: var data = {
        'firstName':$("#firstNameInCreateStudent").val()),
         .........
       'studentSubjects': selSubjectIds
}

data :data